# How to capture rest-client requests from a Rails app using Charles Proxy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, proxy, wireshark, rest-client, charles-proxy

Running a Rails application locally, I am able to configure Charles Proxy to show all the request/response details for the app accessible at lvh.me:3000.

However I haven't been able to capture the rails app internal http calls to external urls. For e.g. using the rest-client/httparty when I make an external call to say http://www.google.com from within my Rails app, Charles proxy does not show the server initiated http requests to google.com.

Can some one suggest what configuration I am missing? In Recording Settings > Include > I have added http://www.google.com.

Comment: It would be helpful to add a link to something about Charles Proxy, and to include some command or demonstration of what you have done.  Context that is obvious to you may not be so obvious to others.

Comment: sorry! here is the link to Charles Proxy - http://www.charlesproxy.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to configure the httpclient to use you proxy. If you are using rest-client you only need to set the proxy address to Charles proxy. E.g. RestClient.proxy = "http://127.0.0.1:8881"

Answer (score 1):

Or if it's httpclient:

http_client = HTTPClient.new(proxy: "127.0.0.1:8888")

...